# How to set a Max number of parallel VM flows

Tags: mule

I have a request-response flow that starts with VM. Is there a way to restrict a number of the requests that could be processed in parallel by the flow?  I'm on 3.7. Thanks.

Ps. I've tried using maxThreadsActive in VM connector but it still runs in the "source" thread. This is how the VM connector in defined:

```
<vm:connector name="myvm" validateConnections="true" doc:name="VM">
        <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="1"/>
        <vm:queue-profile>
          <default-in-memory-queue-store/>
       </vm:queue-profile>
</vm:connector>
```

and then in the flow:

```
<vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="myqueue" connector-ref="myvm" doc:name="getevent">
    <vm:transaction action="NONE"/>
</vm:inbound-endpoint>
```

This is how it's called from the "source" flow:

```
<vm:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" path="myqueue" connector-ref="myvm" doc:name="VM">
    <vm:transaction action="NONE"/>
</vm:outbound-endpoint>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the number of receiver threads for the connector or your inbound-endpoint to one:

```
<vm:connector name="VM" validateConnections="true">
    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="1"/>
</vm:connector>
<flow name="testFlow1">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint path="in" connector-ref="VM"/>
    <echo-component/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the Studio is missing the configuration option. You need to go to the XML in order to set this.

Comment: Ok, actually, this still doesn't work with synchronous flows. For example, Flow1 starts with HTTP request-response connector. Flow 1 is doing request-response on the Flow2 via vm. I would like to limit a number of threads for the Flow2 so I configure the VM connector with maxThreadsActive="1". However, this parameter will be ignored as the Flow2 will be actually executed on the same thread as the Flow1. I don't wanna put limit on on the number of the incoming HTTP threads. Instead, I wanna them waiting on the VM for the Flow2 response. How to do that?

Comment: If you are working synchronously you cannot do that, you should do that asynchronously.

Comment: Ok, what I would have to do to make it asynchronous in the scenario I've described?

Comment: VM transport is asynchronous by default, if you don't configure it to be synchronous, use request response exchange pattern or have a transaction it will work.

Comment: Nope, it still runs in the "source" (HTTP) thread. I can see it in the debugger. I've added the VM definition I use in the original question text.

Answer (score 0):

You can control this with the threading profiles. For example:

```
<configuration >
    <default-threading-profile maxBufferSize="100" maxThreadsActive="20" maxThreadsIdle="10" threadTTL="60000" poolExhaustedAction="RUN" />
</configuration>
```

You can read more here: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/tuning-performance